# Multiple sessions on Stored Procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, session, stored-procedures, multiple-instances

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server in which I am creating couple of temp tables within and manipulating them as per my business logic and at the end I’m deleting those temp tables by using drop table query in the procedure itself.

I have a question, if multiple users are operating at the same time the what will be the case of temp tables? Will it provide multiple instances as sessions in asp.net or only one instance will be available for all users?

Please suggest a good approach for this.

Comment: You don't have to worry about collisions for regular temporary tables.  Global temporary tables are another matter.

Comment: Explore table type variables and see if it would fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Local [temporary tables](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177399(v=sql.105).aspx#Temporary%20Tables):

> are visible only to the current connection for the user, and they are
>   deleted when the user disconnects from the instance of SQL Server

If your ASP.NET application creates a separate connection for each user request, then each connection will have its own temporary tables - they won't be shared with other users.